# Generic HtmlHelper for creating html table from list of any type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a HtmlHelper for creating a html table. I would like the helper to be able to take a list of any type of object and a list of the properties of the object to display as columns. Something like this:

```
public static HtmlString Table(this HtmlHelper helper, List<T> data, List<string> headers)
    {
        //Tags
        TagBuilder table = new TagBuilder("table");
        TagBuilder tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
        TagBuilder td = new TagBuilder("td");
        TagBuilder th = new TagBuilder("th");

        //Inner html of table
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //Add headers
        foreach (var s in headers)
        {
            th.InnerHtml = s;
            tr.InnerHtml += th.ToString();
        }
        sb.Append(tr.ToString());

        //Add data
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            tr.InnerHtml = "";
            foreach (var h in headers)
            {
                td.InnerHtml = d.h.ToString();
                tr.InnerHtml += td.ToString();
            }
            sb.Append(tr.ToString());
        }

        table.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        return new HtmlString(table.ToString());
    }
```

This code will of course not work, but I am wondering if it would be possible to make something similar? And how I might go about doing that.

**EDIT:**

I chose the following solution, the idea was that the table should only contain the elements specified in the headers list, so this is what i came up with:

```
public static HtmlString Table<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, List<T> data, List<string> headers)
{
    //Tags
    TagBuilder table = new TagBuilder("table");
    TagBuilder tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
    TagBuilder td = new TagBuilder("td");
    TagBuilder th = new TagBuilder("th");

    //Inner html of table
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Add headers
    foreach (var s in headers)
    {
        th.InnerHtml = s;
        tr.InnerHtml += th.ToString();
    }
    sb.Append(tr.ToString());

    //Add data
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        tr.InnerHtml = "";
        foreach (var h in headers)
        {
            td.InnerHtml = d.GetType().GetProperty(h).GetValue(d, null).ToString();
            tr.InnerHtml += td.ToString();
        }
        sb.Append(tr.ToString());
    }

    table.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
    return new HtmlString(table.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Would you be comfortable if I assume that in your `List<T>` that the `T` maps to headers through `public properties`?

Comment: The idea is that one header corresponds to one public property of the T. So i guess the answer is yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public HtmlTable BuildTable<T>(List<T> Data)
{
  HtmlTable ht = new HtmlTable();
  //Get the columns
  HtmlTableRow htColumnsRow = new HtmlTableRow();
  typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(prop =>
                                        {
                                          HtmlTableCell htCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                                          htCell.InnerText = prop.Name;
                                          return htCell;
                                        }).ToList().ForEach(cell => htColumnsRow.Cells.Add(cell));
  ht.Rows.Add(htColumnsRow);
  //Get the remaining rows
  Data.ForEach(delegate(T obj)
  {
    HtmlTableRow htRow = new HtmlTableRow();
    obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(delegate(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
      HtmlTableCell htCell = new HtmlTableCell();
      htCell.InnerText = prop.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
      htRow.Cells.Add(htCell);
    });
    ht.Rows.Add(htRow);
  });
  return ht;
}
```

Try that. You need to call `BuildTable<YourType>(list)`.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough. It atleas got me on the right track. See my edit for the final solution.

Comment: @Maris Surely the code above is more efficient/sufficient? You only have to pass the method a list in the code above and it achieves the same thing does it not? So long as it helped you get where you needed to go that's cool :)

Comment: @Marius I see that you only want specific headers, that wasn't clear at the start I thought you wanted all properties. If you want me to refactor this to do that, I will?

Comment: Sorry about that. Another difference is that my method has to return a HtmlString to be able to render output in a the asp.net mvc View. No need to refactor, I am satisfied with my solution :)

Comment: @Marius I would see it as more efficient becuase you are actually building the `HtmlTable` instead of a string representation. Plus `LINQ` is in play, I just tend to use `LINQ` for it's power - in this case it probably doesn't matter how you do it, I just prefer to use `LINQ` :P

Comment: Well that does not apply in my case as I need the result to be a string.. Just a tip as i can see that you like compact code, the use of `delegate (PropertyInfo prop)` can be replaced by a lambda expression `(prop) =>`

Comment: Noob comment, but could you give an example of how to consume this in the view please?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I updated your code for the .NET core version.
good luck

```
    public static IHtmlContent Table<T>(IList<T> data, IList<(string propertyName, string colName)> headers)
    {
        //Tags
        var table = new TagBuilder("table");
        var tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
        
        //Add headers
        foreach (var s in headers)
        {
            var th = new TagBuilder("th");
            th.InnerHtml.Append(s.colName);
            tr.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(th);
        }
        table.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tr);

        //Add data
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
            foreach (var h in headers)
            {
                var td = new TagBuilder("td");
                td.InnerHtml.Append( d.GetType().GetProperty(h.propertyName).GetValue(d, null)?.ToString());
                tr.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(td);
            }
            
            table.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tr);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share sample input ?

Answer (score 1):

.NETStandard 2.0 can use [HtmlTableHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlTableHelper)

#### Fiddle Demo:

- [HtmlTableHelper ConsoleDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DzddCl)
- [HtmlTableHelper ASP.NET MVC Demo (JQuery DataTable)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u9Ia6M)

#### Extension

**ASP.NET Core MVC:**
Create a IHtmlHelperExtension.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HtmlTableHelper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;

public static class IHtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static HtmlString ToHtmlTable<T>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<T> enums
        , object tableAttributes = null, object trAttributes = null, object tdAttributes = null
        , HtmlTableSetting HTMLTableSetting = null)
    {
        var html = enums.ToHtmlTable(tableAttributes, trAttributes, tdAttributes, HTMLTableSetting);
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }

    public static HtmlString ToHtmlTable<T>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.Data.DataTable datatable
        , object tableAttributes = null, object trAttributes = null, object tdAttributes = null
        , HtmlTableSetting HTMLTableSetting = null)
    {
        var html = datatable.ToHtmlTable(tableAttributes, trAttributes, tdAttributes, HTMLTableSetting);
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }
}
```

razor.cshtml

```
@Html.ToHtmlTable(new[] { new { Name = "ITWeiHan", Age = "25", Gender = "M" } })
/*
Result:<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>ITWeiHan</td><td>25</td><td>M</td></tr></tbody></table>
*/
```

**ASP.NET MVC 5:**
Create a HtmlHelperExtension.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HtmlTableHelper;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static HtmlString ToHtmlTable<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<T> enums
        , object tableAttributes = null, object trAttributes = null, object tdAttributes = null
        , HtmlTableSetting HTMLTableSetting = null)
    {
        var html = enums.ToHtmlTable(tableAttributes, trAttributes, tdAttributes, HTMLTableSetting);
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }

    public static HtmlString ToHtmlTable<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.Data.DataTable datatable
        , object tableAttributes = null, object trAttributes = null, object tdAttributes = null
        , HtmlTableSetting HTMLTableSetting = null)
    {
        var html = datatable.ToHtmlTable(tableAttributes, trAttributes, tdAttributes, HTMLTableSetting);
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }
}
```

#### Demo

**ASP.NET MVC 5 JQuery DataTable Demo:**

```
using HtmlTableHelper;
//..
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var datas = new[] { new { Name = "ITWeiHan", Age = "25",Gender = "M" } };
        ViewBag.Table = datas.ToHtmlTable();
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AspNetMvcDemo</title>
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Table)
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('Table').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```